# Lua / Corona - How do I pass a function as a parameter and then call that function

Tags: function, lua, coronasdk

I am trying to pass a function as a parameter in another function.

High level I have code that creates a popup window.  When I update the popup window with new text, I also want to update the action that happens when the user clicks on the popup window. For example the first time I update the popup window, I might change the Action to be to show the popup window again with new text.   When the user clicks on the second

Here is some sample code to illustrate the concept

```
function doSomething()
   print("this is a sample function")
end

function createPopup()
    local popup = display.newRect  ... create some display object
    function popup:close()
        popup.isVisible = false
     end
    function popup:update(options)
        if options.action then
            function dg:touch(e)

                 -- do the action which is passed as options.action

            end
        end
    end
    popup:addEventListener("touch",popup)
    return popup
end

local mypopup = createPopup()

mypopup:update({action = doSomething()})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call it like this

```
function doSomething()
   print("this is a sample function")
end

function createPopup()
    local popup = display.newRect  ... create some display object
    function popup:close()
        popup.isVisible = false
     end
    function popup:update(options)
        if options.action then
            function dg:touch(e)
                options.action() -- This is how you call the function
            end
        end
    end
    popup:addEventListener("touch",popup)
    return popup
end

local mypopup = createPopup()

mypopup:update({action = doSomething})
```

Comment: Shouldn't be calling `doSomething` in the table constructor; Just set the field to the function value itself: `{action = doSomething}`.

Comment: I didn't see that one

Answer (score 0):

i have different approach on changing the text message on alert see this code when you click the rectangle it will change the message the second time you click it

```
local Message = "My Message"
local Title = "My Title"
local nextFlag = false


local function onTap()  
local alert = native.showAlert( Title, Message, { "OK", "Cancel" }, onComplete )
end


function onComplete( event )

    if nextFlag == true then
        if "clicked" == event.action then
           local i = event.index
           Message = "My Message"
           Title = "My Title"
           if 1 == i then
           nextFlag = false
           -- you can add an event here
        elseif 2 == i then
           -- if click cancel do nothing
        end
       end

    else
        if "clicked" == event.action then
         local i = event.index
        Message = "Change message"
            Title = "Change Title"
         if 1 == i then
            nextFlag = true
            -- you can add an event here
          elseif 2 == i then
            -- if click cancel do nothing
        end
       end
    end

end

local rectangle = display.newRect(120,200, 100,100)
rectangle:addEventListener("tap", onTap)
```